# How to call sequential action one after another -- and make sure both get rendered (react-redux)?

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-thunk

I want to **add an item** using a `POST` request, then **close the pop-up window** and **update the item list** with a `GET` request. Using `redux-thunk`, I could call the 2 latter actions after the getting result from `POST`.

Now I want to call **loadAll** action to populate the updated list of item and finish the state change/rendering before calling **toggleAddItem**, which actually close the pop-up window.

```
export const loadAllItems = items => ({
    type: LOAD_ALL_ITEMS,
    payload: items
});

export const toggleAddItem = status => ({
    type: TOGGLE_ADD_ITEM,
    payload: status
})

export const loadAll = () => (dispatch => {
    axios.get('/getAllItems').then(res => {
        dispatch(loadAllItems(res.data))
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
    })
});

export const addItemAndRefresh = input => ((dispatch, getState) => {
axios.post('/addItem', input)
  .then(() => {
      axios.get('/getAllItems')
      .then(res => {
          dispatch(loadAll(res.data))
      })
      .then(() => {
          dispatch(toggleAddItem(false));
      })
  })
  .catch(err => {
      console.log(err);
  })
});
```

With the above code, I manage to call the **loadAll** before **toggleAddItem**. However, with componentDidUpdate log, I realize that **toggleAddItem** actually fires when **loadAll** is still updating state/rendering and even finish before the former action.

So far, this is my best attempt, however, I'm not sure if this sequence can avoid all issues. There are previous cases when pop-up window is closed, and state is updated with new items. However, new item list is not rendered (I suspect that this happens because I update the state while the rendering function is working, so it skips the second render).

*What would be the best implementation for dispatching consequential actions and make sure that both will be rendered?*

Answer (score 1):

You need to call `then` on the promise returned from the `loadAll` action.

Firstly return that promise by changing your `loadAll` to:

```
export const loadAll = () => dispatch => {
    return axios.get('/getAllItems')
      .then(res => {
          dispatch(loadAllItems(res.data))
      })
      .catch(err => {
          console.log(err);
      })
};
```

Then in your `mapDispatchToProps` call `then` and then pass a function which will be called when `loadAll` resolves.

```
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
  addItemAndRefresh: dispatch(loadAll())
                      .then(() => dispatch(toggleAddItem(false)))
});
```